# What does this binomial coefficient property mean?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The following binomial coefficient property, $\displaystyle \sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\binom{k+s}{k}=\binom{n+k}{k+1}$, is described in the book *Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering*—by K.F.Riley—with n being the number of terms, the s being the lower summation index, and k being a fixed parameter. However, I do not understand how the three variables work in this formula as I am only used to seeing two variables (K and N usually) in the binomial coefficient properties. Please, if you could, describe what this formula means and the role each of the three variables play in the formula.

Comment: So, what does this mean for Pascal's Triangle?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Comment: Okay, thank you for the link, it is truly helpful. @RobPratt